# Unresolved external symbols in sample code from Microsoft with Compression API

Tags: c++, compression

I try to use Compression API from Microsoft, but can't even build sample code, because have unresolved external symbol errors. Should I link something else? On Microsoft site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cmpapi/using-the-compression-api-in-buffer-mode you can read "Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012: To use the following example code, you must be running Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 and have "compressapi.h" and "cabinet.dll" and link to the "Cabinet.lib"." I'm using Windows 10. So should I add Cabinet.lib (where could I find it?) or I have it on Windows 10 already?

Code exactly same like on site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `cabinet.lib` to linker dependencies.